Error installing Oracle Application Test Suite with XE database 21c
I'm trying to get OATS (Oracle Application Test Suite) 13.3.0.1 on Windows 11. The documentation states that this software requires Oracle Database (Either EE or XE) I've installed XE version 21c. However after the installation completes, the Oracle ATS Server service will not start.  Looking in the dbsetup.log file shows the following error has occurred:

"Exception:ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name"

Searching the web for this error message brings me to an Oracle Support page that states:

"If you install Oracle Database 12c before installing Oracle Application Testing Suite, you must clear the "Create a Container Database" option (which is selected by default) in the Oracle Universal Installer."

In 21c it doesn't appear that I am able to uncheck the option.  (It is grayed out) looking further into this it appears that later versions of Oracle Database only allow CDBs.  Is there any workaround for this issue outside of trying to hunt down an older version of Oracle Database?

Have you try to install old Oracle XE version? For example 18?
